# Overwrite subdirectory's variable CMAKE_BINARY_DIR

Tags: cmake

I use Googletest library as a `git submodule` and I would like to move its build artifacts in a designated folder, however inside of `googletest/CMakeLists.txt` (that I would like to avoid changing) it hardcodes artifacts path to

```
${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/lib
```

and unfortunately maintainers didn't use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}` instead to add their artifacts in their local build path that I specify using `add_subdirectory` command in my own `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(${VENDOR_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest ${VENDOR_BINARY_DIR}/googletest)
```

Some artifacts respect the second path, but those hardcoded with aforementioned line don't.

Is there a way to overwrite Googletest's local value of `${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}` without forking/modifying the library's `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set dir on gtest target:

```
function target_set_dir(target dir)
    set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES
        CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${dir}
        CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${dir}
        CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${dir}
    )
endfunction()

target_set_dir(gtest ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR]/gtest})
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already come up with something similar after noticing that they use `set_target_properties` to hardcode these values. Count this as an answer